# Multidimensional induction for $m$ variables

Tags: reference-request, induction

I am interested in establishing a form of multidimensional induction where I would like to establish  **$P(n_1, n_2, n_3, ..., n_m)$** for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show that $\forall n_1, n_2,\ldots, n_m \geq 0$, $P(n_1, n_2, n_3, ..., n_m)$ is true.

Similar questions on Math SE are included [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574600/multidimensional-induction-for-n-variables) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869987/proof-by-induction-on-r-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1). I'm not aware of a general technique or strategy for $m>2$. I am also considering $0$ as a natural number so that I write the indices as **$P(0, 0, n_j, \ldots, 0)$** instead of **$P(1, 1, n_j, \ldots, 1)$** (although, I don't see any concern with using $1$ or $0$ for the indices).

Here are my proposed strategies for the case $m=2,m=3,$ and $m=m$. I don't think my way of performing the induction is standard and might be doing some additional work as opposed to the minimum needed.

---

Case $1$ ($m=2$): Establish **$P(n_1, n_2)$** for all $n_1,n_2 \geq 0$ (Induct on $n_2$).

1. Establish **$P(n_1, 0)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$.
2. Given **$P(n_1, n_2)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$, $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$, establish **$P(n_1, \bar{n}_2)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$. This can be accomplished through the two steps below:

   - (a) Establish **$P(0, \bar{n}_2)$** for all $\bar{n}_2\geq 0$ (where the hypothesis in step $2$ gives the required case for $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$).
   - (b) Given **$P(n_1, \bar{n}_2)$** for all $n_1 < \bar{n}_1$, $\bar{n}_2 \geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1, \bar{n}_2)$**.

---

Case $2$ ($m=3$): Establish **$P(n_1, n_2,n_3)$** for all $n_1,n_2,n_3 \geq 0$ (Induct on $n_3$).

1. Establish **$P(n_1, 0,0)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$.
2. Given **$P(n_1, n_2,0)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$, $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$, establish **$P(n_1, \bar{n}_2,0)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$. This can be accomplished through the two steps below:

   - (a) Establish **$P(0, \bar{n}_2,0)$** for all $\bar{n}_2\geq 0$ (where the hypothesis in step $2$ gives the required case for $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$).
   - (b) Given **$P(n_1, \bar{n}_2,0)$** for all $n_1 < \bar{n}_1$, $\bar{n}_2 \geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1, \bar{n}_2,0)$**.
3. Given **$P(n_1, 0,n_3)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$, $n_3 < \bar{n}_3$, establish **$P(n_1, 0,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_1 \geq 0$. This can be accomplished through the two steps below:

   - (a) Establish **$P(0, 0,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $\bar{n}_3\geq 0$ (where the hypothesis in step $3$ gives the required case for $n_3 < \bar{n}_3$).
   - (b) Given **$P(n_1, 0,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_1 < \bar{n}_1$, $\bar{n}_3 \geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1, 0,\bar{n}_3)$**.
4. Establish **$P(0, n_2,0)$** for all $n_2 \geq 0$.
5. Given **$P(0, n_2,n_3)$** for all $n_2 \geq 0$, $n_3 < \bar{n}_3$, establish **$P(0, n_2,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_2 \geq 0$. This can be accomplished through the step below (as the base case for **$P(0, 0,\bar{n}_3)$** is handled in step $3a$).

   - (a) Given **$P(0, n_2,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$, $\bar{n}_3 \geq 0$, establish **$P(0, \bar{n}_2,\bar{n}_3)$**.
6. Given **$P(n_1, n_2,n_3)$** for all $n_1,n_2 \geq 0, n_3 < \bar{n}_3$, establish **$P(n_1, n_2,\bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_1,n_2 \geq 0.$ This can be accomplished through the step below (once again, the base case is handled by previous steps $2,3,3a,5$).

   - (a) Given **$P(n_1, n_2, \bar{n}_3)$** for all $n_1 < \bar{n}_1$, $n_2 < \bar{n}_2$, $\bar{n}_3 \geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1, \bar{n}_2, \bar{n}_3)$**.

---

Case $3$ ($m=m$): Establish **$P(n_1, n_2,\ldots,n_m)$** for all $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m \geq 0$ (Induct on $n_m$).

1. Establish **$P(0,\ldots,n_j,\ldots,0)$** for all $1 \leq j < m$ and $n_1,\ldots,n_j \geq 0.$
2. Given **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_j,\ldots,0)$** for all $1 \leq j < m$ and $n_1,\ldots,n_j \geq 0$, establish **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,\bar{n}_j,\ldots,0)$**. This can be accomplished through the two steps below:

   - (a) Establish **$P(0,\ldots,\bar{n}_j,\ldots,0)$** for all $\bar{n}_j \geq 0$ (where the hypothesis in step $2$ gives the required case for $n_j < \bar{n}_j$).
   - (b) Given  **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,\bar{n}_j,\ldots,0)$** for all $1 \leq j < m$ and $n_1 < \bar{n}_1,  n_2 < \bar{n}_2,\ldots, n_{j-1} < \bar{n}_{j-1}$ and $\bar{n}_j\geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1,\bar{n}_2,\ldots,\bar{n}_j,\ldots,0)$**.
3. Given **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_j,n_{j+1},\ldots,0)$** for all $1 \leq j+1 < m$ and $n_1,\ldots,n_{j+1} \geq 0$, establish **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_j,\bar{n}_{j+1},\ldots,0)$**. This can be accomplished through the two steps below:

   - (a)  Establish **$P(0,\ldots,\bar{n}_{j+1},\ldots,0)$** for all $\bar{n}_{j+1} \geq 0.$ (where the hypothesis in step $3$ gives the required case for $n_{j+1} < \bar{n}_{j+1}$).
   - (b)  Given  **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_j,\bar{n}_{j+1},\ldots,0)$** for all $1 \leq j+1 < m$ and  $n_1 < \bar{n}_1,  n_2 < \bar{n}_2,\ldots, n_{j} < \bar{n}_{j}$ and $\bar{n}_{j+1}\geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1,\bar{n}_2,\ldots,\bar{n}_j,\bar{n}_{j+1}\ldots,0)$**.
4. Given **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{m-1},n_m)$** for all $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{m-1} \geq 0$ and $n_m < \bar{n}_m$, establish **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{m-1},\bar{n}_m)$**. This can be accomplished through the two steps below (the base cases are handled by steps $2$ and $3$):

   - (a)  Establish **$P(0,\ldots,\bar{n}_{m})$** for $\bar{n}_{m} \geq 0$ (where from step $4$, we know that this is true for $n_{m} < \bar{n}_{m}$).
   - (b)  Given **$P(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{m-1},\bar{n}_m)$** for all $n_1 < \bar{n}_1, n_2 < \bar{n}_2, \ldots n_{m-1} < \bar{n}_{m-1}$ and $\bar{n}_m \geq 0$, establish **$P(\bar{n}_1,\bar{n}_2,\ldots,\bar{n}_{m-1},\bar{n}_m)$**.

---

I don't recall seeing many results past the case where $m=2$ (various authors generally show what happens when $m=2$ and then say that "the general case will follow from similar arguments.") If, for example, $m=100$, then is the general procedure to show what happens for $m=2$ and not worry about completing a successful proof for $m=40$ or $m=80$? Is there a published result in a textbook or paper which handles something similar to the general case?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do multi-dimensional induction, and you pick which is most convenient to induct on. EG You can induct on $N = \sum n_i $, like in the case of the multinomial theorem. $\quad$  Alternatively, you can induct on each variable, holding all others constant. This greatly simplifies your case 3. (You have 2 case 3's so ...)

Comment: Why do I have two case $3$? I'm not sure how one would induct on $N=\sum n_i$ and inducted on every variable (as this made the most sense to me). I will review the proof of the multinomial theorem.

Comment: (Oh, I misread, your cases are labelled correctly.)  $\quad$ You induct on $N$, and do the case of figuring out which $n_i$ has increased. If the variables represent similar things, then hopefully you can just show the case of 1 variable.